# How to reduce RMS error in Stereo Camera Calibration

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I used opencv calibration to calibrate my stereo camera, I used get RMS error around 0.35 to 0.5 on different iterations. Whether i have to change the OpenCV flags(in stereocalibrate function) used to based in the applications to better RMS error?

Comment: The calibration returns the reprojection error, which means how far the projected 3D points matches the 2D points given. Then it also raises the question, how accurate are your 2D points? if the points are noisy, it may have "higher" error but the result could be perfect. Also, the error is in pixels normally, and this means that higher resolution may give higher error for the same error in real world units (e.g. mm) My point is, that having better error does not necessarily mean that the code is wrong or the images are totally wrong.

Comment: To check my stereo camera calibration is perfect i should not depend on RMS values? My camera is resolution is 2MP(1600x1300).  How to check my camera calibration is perfect.  Before taking the depth measurement.